# Using powershell to create a PDF

Tags: powershell, pdf, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, com-object

I am working on a script to create a PDF from PowerShell. I have it working using Word, using the ComObject. But that means that computer I run it on has to have Word. I was wandering if there was a way to make a PDF file from notepad maybe. This is the code I have making the PDF from Word.

```
<`#make pdf

# Required Word Variables
$wdExportFormatPDF = 17
$wdDoNotSaveChanges = 0

# Create a hidden Word window
$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$word.visible = $false

# Add a Word document
$doc = $word.documents.add()

# Put the text into the Word document
$txt = Get-Content $txtPath
$selection = $word.selection
foreach($line in $txt){
$selection.typeText($line) | Format-wide
$selection.typeparagraph()
}
# Export the PDF file and close without saving a Word document
$doc.ExportAsFixedFormat($pdfPath,$wdExportFormatPDF) 
if($?){write-host 'Users and Groups saved to ' $pdfPath -ForegroundColor Cyan}
$doc.close([ref]$wdDoNotSaveChanges)
$word.Quit()`>
```

Comment: Hi, there is an example here, with a 3rd party library : http://merill.net/2013/06/creating-pdf-files-dynamically-with-powershell/.